# jquery is not working in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

i was working in jQuery but not able to make it work on the template.

forms.py

```
class DowncallForm(forms.ModelForm):
engineer = Engineer.objects.all()

class Meta :
    model = Call
    fields = ['problem_type', 'status', 'remarks', 'call_date', 'exp_closing_time', 'tat',
              'assigned_engineer']
class Media:
    js = ('js/downcall_validation.js',)
```

downcall.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Downcall Detail</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/downcall_validation.js" %}"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    {% block content %}
        {{ DowncallForm.media }}
 <form method="post" action="" id="downcall_register_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
 <div id="div_id_tat" class="form-group">
     <label for="id_tat" class="control-label  requiredField">
     Tat<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
     </label>
     <div class="controls ">
     <input class="numberinput form-control" id="id_tat" name="tat" type="number" />
     </div>
     </div>
```

i have included the Media file in my forms.py and loaded the static files in html template as {% load staticfiles %} ...The same steps is working for another template form but no this one..

here is the jquery file.. downcall_validation.js

```
$(document).ready.(function() {
    alert("hai");
  //  Setup form validation on the #register-form element
    //  downcall_register_form==> form id
  $("#downcall_register_form").validate({

      //$("#id_tat").rules("add", {min: 1}),

      // Specify the validation rules
      //id_tat==> id of the input element
      rules: {
          id_tat: {
              min: 1
          }
      },

      // Specify the validation error messages
      messages: {
          id_tat: "Please enter a positive number"
      }

      //    submitHandler: function(form) {
      //        form.submit();
      //    }
      //});

  });
```

});

I have included the javascript libraries also, eventhough its not working.

Comment: What does "its not working" mean?

Comment: i am trying to set the minimum value for the tat element in html...but the jquery file is not running.

Comment: You need to clearly say what do you want to do, what have you tried, what is the result you're getting and what is the result you are expecting.

Comment: i tried using this method:
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    .
    .
    class Media:
        js = ('js/customer_detail.js',)
and then include it like {{<yourformname>.media}} in your template, And write your javascript code inside that customer_detail.js

i added just the alert() function in the jquery to test whether its running or not but its not running in my template..

Comment: I am inheriting the js files from the base.html, For the customer_detail.html  jquery is running and for the other templates jquery is not running and its not showing any error.

Answer (score 1):

You should be more specific about what "it's not working" means.

However one obvious mistake is that you are including your own script file - which depends on jQuery - before you load jQuery itself, which will fail. Move your script tag to after the jquery ones.

Also, you are including both jQuery and jquery-validate twice, from different targets. Don't do that; pick one and use it.

Comment: i tried using this method:
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    .
    .
    class Media:
        js = ('js/customer_detail.js',)
and then include it like {{<yourformname>.media}} in your template, And write your javascript code inside that customer_detail.js

i added just the alert() function in the jquery to test whether its running or not but its not running in my template..

Answer (score 0):

There was a dot in your call to the jQuery `ready` function...

```
$(document).ready.(function() {
```

should be...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```